# dataframe select a word on the text

Tags: python, regex, pandas

i have a datafame in input and i want to extract in column "localisation" the word in this list ["SECTION 11","CÔNE","BELLY"] and i have to create new column "word"
in the dataframe. If the word of the list exist in the the column "localisation" i fill the word in the column created "word".otherwise i put the full text in the column "word"
This my dataframe
[image]

I create new column "word"
I selected the line containing the words from the list
I fill in the "word" column with the keywords found from the list

```
["SECTION 11","CÔNE","BELLY"]
df["temp"]=df["localisation"].str.extract("Localisation[\s]*:.*\n([^_\n]{3,})\n[^\n]*\n")
df["word"]=df["temp"].str.extract("(SECTION 11|CÔNE|BELLY)")
df["temp"]=df["localisation"].str.extract("Localisation[\s]*:.*\n([^_\n]{3,})\n[^\n]*\n")
df["word"]=df["temp"].str.extract("(SECTION 11|CÔNE|BELLY)")
```

my problem I can not put the full text if the word of the list is not found in the column "localization". I have null values ​​in the lines or I have to put the full text

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.fillna` with the `df["localisation"]` as argument:

```py
df["word"]=df["localisation"].str.extract(r"\b(SECTION 11|CÔNE|BELLY)\b", expand=False).fillna(df["localisation"])
```

Note also that I suggested `r"\b(SECTION 11|CÔNE|BELLY)\b"`, a regex with word boundaries to only match your alternatives as whole words. Note that word boundaries `\b` are Unicode-aware in Python `re` that is used behind the scenes in Pandas.

If you do not need the whole word search, you may keep using `r"SECTION 11|CÔNE|BELLY"`.